# Why *.Designer.cs file sometimes is created with small "d" letter and other times with big "D" letter?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I had a problem to switch to another git branch, because it was complaining `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout (..)`
And named file seemed to be added to git… then I took a look at the branch I am trying to switch to and noticed that it had 2 designer files:
MyForm.**D**esigner.cs and MyForm.**d**esigner.cs

Then I took a look at my code and noticed that for some winforms I have this file with lower case "d" (but most cases are with upper case). I know that I have not changed this manually. Did not get any explanation from search engine…  may someone knows what could cause this effect?

Comment: are there other developers contributing, who use different version(s) of Visual Studio?

Comment: IIRC, I saw this once. It was coming from a Form Template, used as a base for some UI rendering. The `.vstemplate` file actually had the internal names set in lower case (the Form `.designer.cs` file also in lower case).

Comment: @dlatikay no, I am working alone on that project, and from one machine